# How do I pass an arbitrary number of strings to a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am coming from a PostgreSQL background and there I could write the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.text_column = ANY(:input::text[])
```

In this query, I am passing an array of string values. This allowed me to pass any number of input parameters, without knowing the size in advance.

How would you do this in MySQL? I am targeting MySQL 8, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the IN keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.text_column IN('item1','item2','item3');
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx

Edit: Without changing the query: If you create a temporary table for the list of items, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.text_column IN  
(SELECT item from temptable);
```

Comment: This means that I have to adapt the query to the number of items being passed. I would rather not dynamically change/write SQL queries.

Comment: Uploading all items to a (temporary) table, and using 'IN (SELECT item From temptable)' would be better for You?

Comment: Temporary table is a great idea! I'll experiment with that.

Comment: Great! I upvoted it. I'll wait for possible other useful answers. If not, I will accept later!

Comment: Another way would be to create a non-aggregate user defined function (UDF, avalaible in 8.x) to provide the functionality of ANY(). But I'm not familiar with that stuff.

Comment: Interesting, would it be possible to pass an arbitrary size of items to that UDF?

Comment: @JellyOrns See here: https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/misc/article.php/c12615/MySQL-UDFs.htm